# How to import a packge from a local jar in pyspark?

Tags: csv, pyspark

I am using pyspark to do some work on a csv file, hence I need to import package from spark-csv_2.10-1.4.0.jar downloaded from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/databricks/spark-csv_2.11/1.4.0/spark-csv_2.11-1.4.0.jar

I downloaded the jar to my local due to proxy issue.

Can anyone tell me what is the right usage of referring to a local jar:

Here is the code I use:

```
pyspark --jars /home/rx52019/data/spark-csv_2.10-1.4.0.jar
```

it will take me to the pyspark shell as expected, however, when I run:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true',inferschema='true').load('hdfs://dev-icg/user/spark/routes.dat')
```

the route.dat is uploaded to hdfs already at hdfs://dev-icg/user/spark/routes.dat

It gives me error:

> : java.lang.**NoClassDefFoundError**: **org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat**

If I run:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true',inferschema='true').load('routes.dat')
```

I get this error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o72.load.
>   : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: **Could not initialize class
>   com.databricks.spark.csv.package$**

Can anyone help to sort it out for me? Thank you very much. Any clue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be to add the options (say if you are starting a spark shell)

```
spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0 --driver-class-path /path/to/csvfilejar.jar
```

I have not used the databricks csvjar directly, but I used a netezza connector to spark where they mention using this option

https://github.com/SparkTC/spark-netezza

Comment: Thank you. My working folder is /home/rr52019/data, the jar file is in the working folder, I am using pyspark, here is the command:
pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0 --driver-class-path /spark-csv_2.10-1.4.0.jar
 and it prompts error: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: com.databricks#spark-csv_2.11;1.4.0: not found]